# Chrome: Find changes vs default settings

Tags: google-chrome

I am using Chrome on a Chromebook/ChromeOS. I am about to set developper mode, that means erasing all settings, and reverting back to default settings. To ease the recovery, I would like to know what are the settings that I have set since a long time, and be able to choose if I keep those settings or not.

Is there a way to highlight what are the changes I've made versus the default settings of chrome?

Comment: What do you mean with "settings", the normal user settings or the hidden advanced settings?

Comment: @nullterminatedstring, I would say any setting that I could have changed, and that I cannot remember. So both normal user settings and hidden advanced settings. You're probably asking the question because you know how to do for one but not the other? I'm interested in all tricks that could do for any group of settings.

Comment: You could at first make screenshots of the few "normal" user setting, then you could use "chrome://flags" to open the advanced settings , now all modified variables will appear brighter and not so gray.That should include all chrome settings except extension specific ones but I can't say for sure.

Comment: You might have changed settings in some very special menus like the Accessibility menu to check that setting you could go through all urls at "chrome://chrome-urls"